# After boot gui login forgets about user

Tags: login, users

Hello ubuntu community,

I hope you can help me to learn more about ubuntu and get my system starting correct again.

**What happend**

I used the system with ubuntu 20.04 LTS for two month without any problem.

Today instead of the login, I was prompted the creation of a new user.
(This looks just like the first the boot after a fresh installation.)

After creating a new user, I logged out. Only the new user was displayed.

I logged back in an checked the home repository and list all users with
`cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`. Both showed the original user and the new user.

Switched to terminal mode (Ctrl+Alt+F3) and tried to login with the original user.
This was not successful.

But after switching back to gui and logging out. I could select the original user
and login successful.

Hoped it was a strange hiccup and deleted new user. But with the next reboot I was prompted the creation of a new user again.

When restarting with the new user, I can select something like "not listed users" to login as original user.

I was installing and removing some packages before this happened,but I am not aware that I fiddled config of gui.

**Questions:**

How to inspect this further? What change could create this behaviour?

Can it be fixed cleanly, or is a reinstall of parts or system necessary?